# AWK - If column in Test2 found in line in Test1 insert 1 else 0 in Test1

Tags: awk

I have two files Test1 and Test2.

Test1:

```
10AP23Q   ERTY
10AP20J   FDGC
978J15K   BGTD
98KT23M   ERTY
76VU14P   FDGC
```

Test2:

```
23
19
15
```

Test1 is a fixed width file. If the  column in Test2 found in  line in Test1, insert ‘1’ , else insert ‘0’ at position 9 in Test1.

Expected output:

```
10AP23Q 1 ERTY
10AP20J 0 FDGC
978J15K 1 BGTD
98KT23M 1 ERTY
76VU14P 0 FDGC
```

I tried the below code. Getting parse error near '}'.

```
awk 'BEGIN {if('NR==FNR {a[$1];next} (substr($0,5,2) in a)' test2 test1) (substr($0,9,1)="1") else(substr($0,9,1)="0")}'
```

Appreciate the solution.

Comment: deleted the images and files are in text format

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to do it:

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}
       {$9 = ($5$6 in a) ? 1 : 0} 1' Test2 Test1
10AP23Q 1 ERTY
10AP20J 0 FDGC
978J15K 1 BGTD
98KT23M 1 ERTY
76VU14P 0 FDGC
```

- `FS=OFS=""` clear `FS` and `OFS` so that each field is individual characters, makes it easier to write a solution compared to using `substr`
- `NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}` create array keys based on entire line contents of `Test2`
- `$9 = ($5$6 in a) ? 1 : 0` check if 5th/6th character sequence from `Test1` is present as a key in the array and change 9th character accordingly

  - Instead of ternary operator, you can also use `$9 = ($5$6 in a)` since `in` returns `1` for *true* case and `0` for *false* case (courtesy: [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava))
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  $1=$1 OFS ((substr($1,5,2) in arr)?"1":"0")
}
1
' Test2 Test1
```

OR as per anubhava sir's nice suggestion, above could be shorten to:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  $1=$1 OFS (substr($1,5,2) in arr)
}
1
' Test2 Test1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '               ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{            ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when Test2 is being read.
  arr[$0]           ##Creating array arr with index of current line.
  next              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  $1=$1 OFS ((substr($1,5,2) in arr)?"1":"0") ##Checking condition if sub string of 1st field is present in array then add 1 else add 0 here into $1 itself.
}
1                   ##1 will print current line here.
' Test2 Test1       ##mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: All the solutions worked on my data sets. Thank you all for your help. Appreciate your quick responses.

Comment: @mnr, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

Since the requirement was *If the column in Test2 found in line in Test1* I'm not limiting the search to character positions 5 & 6:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                                       # process file2
    r=r (r==""?"":"|") $0                       # build a regex of data (23|19|15)
    next
}
{                                               # process file1
    print substr($0,1,8) ($0~r) substr($0,10)   # output: 1-8 condition 9-
    # print $1,($0~r),$2                        # coincidently this would work also 
}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
10AP23Q 1 ERTY
10AP20J 0 FDGC
978J15K 1 BGTD
98KT23M 1 ERTY
76VU14P 0 FDGC
```

If the contents of `file2` are only found in positions 5 & 6, this solution is ineffective compared to the two other solutions (presented this point).